Flutter App Icon Invisible/Empty After Adding My Own
I tried following this tutorial: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons
So I set these keys in my pubspec.yaml:
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.14.1"

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon2.png"

and executed:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons

Get noticed some outdated packages, but I thought it should still work:
Resolving dependencies... 
Downloading packages... 
  collection 1.18.0 (1.19.0 available)
  leak_tracker 10.0.5 (10.0.7 available)
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing 3.0.5 (3.0.8 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.11.1 (0.12.0 available)
  meta 1.15.0 (1.16.0 available)
  string_scanner 1.2.0 (1.3.0 available)
  test_api 0.7.2 (0.7.3 available)
Got dependencies!
7 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons succeeded without issues. I later tested that it actually found the file by letting it look for a file that doesn't exist and it threw an error as expected:
Deprecated. Use `dart run` instead.
Building package executable... 
Built flutter_launcher_icons:flutter_launcher_icons.
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.14.1)                               
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
  
• Creating default icons Android
• Adding a new Android launcher icon
• Creating mipmap xml file Android

WARNING: Icons with alpha channel are not allowed in the Apple App Store.
Set "remove_alpha_ios: true" to remove it.

• Overwriting default iOS launcher icon with new icon
No platform provided

✓ Successfully generated launcher icons

After executing all this and running the app via usb debugging on my android mobile phone, the app no longer has an icon (what I called invisible above). Before that it showed the generic flutter icon.
I have repeated the process with flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main and dart run flutter_launcher_icons instead and have also tried removing the alpha channel from the icon. This didn't change the result. The icon is a 512x512 png.
I am unsure on how to debug this issue further.
Using Chris suggestion
# flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons
flutter_launcher_icons:
  image_path: "assets/images/icon2.png"

  android: "launcher_icon"
  # image_path_android: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  # adaptive_icon_background: "assets/icon/background.png"
  # adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icon/foreground.png"
  # adaptive_icon_monochrome: "assets/icon/monochrome.png"

  ios: true
  # image_path_ios: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  remove_alpha_channel_ios: true
  # image_path_ios_dark_transparent: "assets/icon/icon_dark.png"
  # image_path_ios_tinted_grayscale: "assets/icon/icon_tinted.png"
  # desaturate_tinted_to_grayscale_ios: true

  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/icon2.png"
    background_color: "#000000"
    theme_color: "#3d9bd5"

  windows:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/icon2.png"
    icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48

  macos:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/icon2.png"

I set this to be my yaml generated by dart run flutter_launcher_icons:generate  and executed the generation command flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons and dependency command flutter pub get afterwards. I then uninstalled the app and first tried installing the app via usb debugging which did not help. I then uninstalled and build the app explicitly and moved the release apk onto my android phone, but again no icon.

have you tried uninstalling the app on your device and rebuilding it ?

I had only uninstalled and reinstalled it via usb debug, but now I have rebuild the apk, copied it over and installed it there and was able to reproduce the issue that way too

I'm also facing this issue right now, and currently resolved it by simply removing the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder.

flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.14.1"

I'm also using the same version. Seems there is a known issue that not providing adaptive_icon_* will cause generating empty adaptive icon xml files. See the file content under android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder.
The workaround solution is either:

simply delete that mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder, or
provide proper adaptive_icon_foreground and adaptive_icon_background value in your flutter_launcher_icons's configuration file, or
downgrade to a version that doesn't have this issue (0.13.0)

I personally suggest going with the first or second method, then try to build/debug again and you'll see the icon.
Links related to this issue:

Reddit: App icon not showing after building APK, even after following flutter_launcher_icons setup
GitHub Issue: blank launcher icon on build


I was having the same issue but this is how I solved it.
Run this command in your project's directory terminal: dart run flutter_launcher_icons:generate after adding the flutter_launcher_icons to your dependencies.
It will generate flutter_launcher_icons.yaml in the root directory of your project, in the same directory with your pubspec.yaml.
Then run : flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons after configuring flutter_launcher_icons.yaml as below,  remember to run flutter pub get before  building your app
# flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons
flutter_launcher_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icon/yourimage.png"

  android: "launcher_icon"
  # image_path_android: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  # adaptive_icon_background: "assets/icon/background.png"
  # adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icon/foreground.png"

  ios: true
  # image_path_ios: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  remove_alpha_channel_ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true

  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/icon/yourimage.png"
    background_color: "#hexcode"
    theme_color: "#hexcode"

  windows:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/icon/yourimage.png"
    icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48

  macos:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/icon/yourimage.png"


Sadly that did not fix my issue. I commented above how I filled in the flutter_launcher_icons.yaml in case I made a mistake
